# What is happening to the output of this conversion, and why isn't it what I think it should be?

Tags: python, hex, base64, byte, codec

I'm trying to write a short program in Python to convert a string from hex into bytes, and then from bytes into base64. I've got a base string in hexadecimal, and the equivalent of the string in base64. The program looks like this:

```
import codecs

basecode = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d"
DesiredResult = "SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t"
e = codecs.decode(basecode, 'hex')
print(e)
y = codecs.encode(e, 'base64')
print(y)
z = bytes.decode(y, 'utf-8')
print(z)
print(DesiredResult)

if y == DesiredResult:
    print("Success!")
```

The output I'm getting from the program is as follows:

```
b"I'm killing your brain like a poisonous mushroom"
b'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t\n'
SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t

SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t
```

As I'm sure you can imagine, this is frustrating, because it means that while I've come close, I haven't actually done what I set out to do.

So, how can I modify this program to make sure that the output of my conversion is exactly the same as the variable `DesiredResult`?

I know it has to do with the `\n` that appears in the conversion, but I don't know how it gets there, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Any and all suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: encode base64 adds a new line character. So just strip it.

Comment: How can I go about stripping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [base64 codec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) always adds a `\n` byte at the end.

> Convert operand to MIME base64 (the result always includes a trailing '\n')

To strip the last `\n` byte, use the [Python slicing operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) like this:

```
>>> y
'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t\n'
>>> DesiredResult
'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t'
>>> y[:-1]
'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t'
>>> y[:-1] == DesiredResult
True
```

Comment: This is almost working, but the output for me of doing the y[:-1] looks like this:
`b'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t'`

I'm assuming this is because it's stored in byte format - any tips on how to convert it back?